# How to add Semantic-UI LESS to Codeigniter 3.x

Tags: codeigniter, semantic-ui

I want to know how to use Semantic-UI to codeigniter 3.x as frontend framework.

I want to use LESS and not css. thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, it is important to understand that LESS is a CSS pre-compiler that extends the CSS language with features that allows creation of CSS that is more maintainable, themeable and extendable. But ultimately it creates CSS files that are used exactly the same as any other CSS file in a website.

In CodeIgniter you use Semantic-UI created assets the same way as any other CSS (or javascript) files by using a `<link>` tag.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="semantic/dist/semantic.min.css">
<script src="semantic/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
```

The CSS classes are used in "view" files exactly the same way any other CSS defined class. For instance, the following would put a button styled by Semantic-UI into a CodeIgniter "view" file.

```
<button class="ui button">Follow</button>
```

So, the short answer to your question is that you use Semantic-UI in CodeIgniter the same way any other frontend framework that produces CSS and Javascript.

How to use the tools required to customize Semantic-UI is way beyond the scope of what is a "good" question on Stackoverflow.

If you want to customize and build your own version of the UI, you have a steep learning curve ahead. You can start your learning on Semantic-UI's [Getting Started](http://semantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started.html) page and on the [Learn Semantic](http://learnsemantic.com/) website.

Comment: can you show me how to do it, cause i want to switch between semantic-ui themes on across my project.

Comment: I added some to my answer. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have done Semantic UI integration on my CodeIgniter based application starter: https://github.com/ivantcholakov/starter-public-edition-4

For compilation of your own visual themes you need to install locally on your development machine node.js, less.js, postcss/cssnano, they should be able to start from command line.

See the configuration file platform/common/config/less_compile.php there you can define by example your own visual theme. Also, have a look at the already created themes, you will see how to add your common Semantic UI customizations and your theme-specific styles.

Answer (score 0):

add css link in your header and js in your footer

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.3/semantic.min.css">

<script type="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.3/semantic.min.js"></script>
```